# Getting NA with as.POSIXct in R while working on an excel column

Tags: r

I have been working on this data analysis project and I am stuck with converting a column to date time format.
First I imported them
`file_name <- read_csv("C:/Users/DELL/Documents/r_project/project_file.csv")`

Then, `str(file_name)`

Two column names had the type-

```
cols(start_date_time = col_character(), end_date_time = col_character()
```

Then, I turned them into characters-

```r
file_name <- mutate(file_name, start_date_time = as.character(start_date_time), end_date_time = as.character(end_date_time))
```

After another, `str(file_name)` it showed,

```
$ start_date_time        : chr [1:84776] "26-04-2020 17:45" "17-04-2020 17:08" "01-04-2020 17:54" "07-04-2020 12:50" ...
$ end_date_time          : chr [1:84776] "26-04-2020 18:12" "17-04-2020 17:17" "01-04-2020 18:08" "07-04-2020 13:02" ...
```

I wanted the type to be dttm rather than character, so I used,

```r
file_name$start_date_time <- as.POSIXct(file_name$start_date_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")
```

But when I write `str(file_name%start_date_time)`
I get-

```
POSIXct[1:84776], format: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I tried 'with_tz', changed time zones ( the data was supposed to have been collected in America/Chicago- I tried that, used GMT, used my own country and city).

Nothing worked. Replaced `$` with `[[]]`, didn't work. When I view the file it shows the two columns with values as NA but when I check the type it shows double. I need these two columns for subtraction and therefore I refuse to use `POSIXlt`.

I am new to R programming and I have never done a data analysis project before. The names of the files have been changed along with the column names in the question.

Comment: your timestamps look like `26-04-2020 17:45`, so try `format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You can try `anytime::anytime(file_name$start_date_time)`, it does _not_ require a format and will even convert from `factor` to character (if needed). This question is a FAQ so it will likely be closed.  Actually, just checked: your format is too irregular / too far from ISO8601 (and many variants `anytime` heuristically tries) so you must supply the precise format as @Wimpel suggested too.

Comment: The presence of `col_character()` suggests you used `readr::` or `vroom::` to read in the data; they are harmless, your use of `as.character` did nothing to the data other than remove the *attribute* of `col_character()` (it did no harm, too).